# Pass a string from first activity to last activity but running another activity before starting last activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm very new in Android, if the question is repeated please avoid and send the link.
There are three activities A, B and C. Activity A gets a username which I want to get displayed in activity C, but I want to run Activity B first and then run Activity C. The problem using intent is that I have to run C first. If singleton, bundle, or parcelable is the solution can you please provide the code?

**Activity A**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText nameText = findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    nameText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            String name = nameText.getText().toString();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

**Activity B**

```
    public class qPage2 extends AppCompatActivity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_q_page2);
                android.os.SystemClock.sleep(500);
            }
        }
```

**Activity C**

```
public class lastPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_last_page);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy than you thought. For example if you want to send a `Tasif` string from A to C via B.

In activity A

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
intent.putExtra("username", "Tasif");
startActivity(intent);
```

In activity B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
intent.putExtras(getIntent()); // Add this line, it will copy all data in intent which starts activity B (including `username`).
startActivity(intent);
```

In activity C

```
String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
```

Comment: i understand, what if you have multiple activities between A and C , then you would have have to write via all the activities so i was wondering whether there was any other short method.

Comment: For each activity, you just add one line `intent.putExtras(getIntent())`, if you think is not good solution then you can use `SharedPreferences`. But from my point, I will stick with sending data via intent because we do not need to save any persistent data. It's up to you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for this :

1. You can use intent as you mentioned
2. You can make a static Class and declare a static variable with type string 
   and access it in the C activity .

Code For first option :
For adding value to intent

```
 Intent n = new Intent(FirstActivity.class,SecondActivity.class);
n.putExtra("name" , name);
n.startActivity();
```

For retrieving it :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

2.Create a static class member and acess it

```
class static StaticClass{
     static name = " ";
 }
```

Update this variable in the first activity and retrive it in last activity

Comment: for first option - I want to pass it to the third activity, if use your code will it be passed to the third activity and then the second will start and then the third?

Comment: Pass the string to the last activity from the Middleton activity

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `String` inside Activity "A" as `public static`  and store the string in it from Activity "A" .

eg: Activity A.java

```
 public static String first = "hello";
```

Then in Activity "C" call it like

Actiivity C.java

```
String last = A.first;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store that string in `SharedPreferences` and can access that string anywhere in your project. If you are not familiar with `SharedPreferences` read the documentation from this [SharedPrefernces Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

Answer (score 0):

A simple and clean approach is to use SharedPreferences data storage option. It is used to save a small collection of data like Key-Value pair.

Save the username in SharedPreferences as below in Activity A:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
    getString("MyKeyPairFileName"), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPref.edit().putString("userKey", "Your username").apply;
```

Read the value from any Activity(B or C or D or...Z) as below:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
    getString("MyKeyPairFileName"), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = sharedPref.getString("userKey", null);
/*null is the default value, if value for the key is not available*/);
```

Be careful when using `getSharedPreferences` vs `getPreferences` from Activity. You can read more on SharedPreferences [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java)